# How can I add it to Icon with svg extension?

Tags: flutter, svg, icons, extension-methods

I want to create my own icons. For this, I created CustomIcon with the extension.

```
extension CustomIcons on Icon {
  Icon get panelIcon =>Icon(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset("asset/svg/one.svg", semanticsLabel: 'One') ,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
     
}
```

}

I want to use my CustomIcon in the form of Icon(Icons.panelIcon). I am getting the error in the photo. How can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzRmj.png)

Comment: 1) `Icon` is different with `Icons`. 2) The icons you usually use, like `Icons.person`, are static members of the `Icons` class, you can't make an extension on it. 3) `SvgPicture.asset` is a widget, you can't put it inside `Icon`. 4) `Icon` takes `IconData`as its first positional parameter. There's no named parameter `icon`.

Comment: You might want to learn how to implement your own `IconData` by looking the source code of this package: https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Few things to know :

- The parameter `icon` of `Icon` class is of type `IconData?`.
- `IconData` is font character and not an image. It is part of "MaterialIcons" font.

[image]

##### Here are the steps to achieve it :

1. Make an extension on `Icons` class and not `Icon`.
2. Create a custom font with your svg pictures using this website : https://icomoon.io/app
3. Import the font in your flutter project assets
4. Write your code like so

```dart
extension customIcons on Icons {
  static IconData panelIcon = const IconData(0x[CHARACTER_CODE], fontFamily: 'YourCustomIconFont');
}
```

**NB:** You will easily get CHARACTER_CODE on iconmoon.io. Check this as example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to extend `Icon` widget with custom icons, but this is how I suggest doing it:

```
class CustomIcons {
  static Image panelIcon = Image.asset(
    'asset/svg/one.svg',
  );
}
```

Then you can simply use it by calling:

```
CustomIcons.panelIcon;
```